# Will the following PHP script work using this PHP client: https://github.com/cturbelin/rserve-php with Rserve?

Tags: php, r, graph, data-analysis, rserve

```
<?php 
    require_once 'config.php';
    require '/../Connection.php';
    $r = new Rserve_Connection(RSERVE_HOST);
    $r->evalString("df=('new1.csv')");
    $r->evalString("values<-df$TOTAL_PURCHASE");
    $r->evalString("s1<-ts(values,frequency=1)");
    $r->evalString("library(forecast)");
    $r->evalString("f1<-auto.arima(s1)");
    $r->evalString("f2<-forecast(f1)");
    $r->evalString("plot(f2,main="PURCHASE PREDICTIONS")");
    $r->close();
?>
```

My main doubt is because I am plotting a graph inside the script and not just displaying values. I am unable to test it out because of some restrictions and any feedback along with reasons would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: If you can't test it....

Comment: I know. But I am having certain problems with my xampp and am stuck with just writing code at the moment. I know it is too much to ask but I just want to know if it atleast seems right and should work theoretically.